# Determine if the content of a file/directory exist for more than 2 hours

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, centos7

I try to create a bash script that determine if the content of a `.txt` file or a directory is older than 2 hours and then return it to me, where hour should be a configurable variable.
What  I have till now is not working unfortunately. Can you help :) ?

```
#!/bin/sh

#Determine how old is the file
old=`find /opt/import/dev -ctime -20m`


If [ -n $old ]
then
echo "old files found:"
echo /n $old
```

Comment: `[ -n $old ]` will fail if `old` contains spaces, tabs and newlines, like it does with `find` output. Do `[ -n "$old" ]`.

Answer (score 1):

To get the list of files modified less than `$hour` hours ago, you have to use next arguments for the command `find`:

```
((min = hour * 60))
old=$( find /opt/import/dev -cmin -$min )
```